# In the Google Play Store, how does the Internal Test Track interact with Production updates?

Tags: google-play

If I publish v10 of my app into Internal Test Track, and then a day later publish v11 of my app into Production, will the people in my Internal Test Track get the update? Or are they stuck on whatever is the latest version in Internal Test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User will always receive the highest version available to them. See [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) under "Version code requirements". So if version on Internal Test track is lower than on Production, they will get production.